# Apagar equipos en red mediante C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows10

estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño programa para windows 10 en c# el cual apague desde un equipo A varios equipos dentro de la misma red, he buscado y no he encontrado info util, ojala puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias evaluar usar `WMI` usando `Win32_OperatingSystem`

```
string remotePC = string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", computerName);
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(remotePC, options);
scope.Connect();

SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_OperatingSystem");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

foreach (ManagementObject os in searcher.Get())
{
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = os.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown");

    inParams["Flags"] =  2;

    ManagementBaseObject outParams = os.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", inParams, null);
}
```

usando WMI puedes ejecutar la accion de forma remota

[WMI to reboot remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921905/wmi-to-reboot-remote-machine)

Comment: en tu código no veo el envío de credenciales, creo que solo funcionará en una red Windows con dominio cuando lo mande llamar un usuario administrador del dominio, corrígeme si me equivoco por favor.

Comment: claro entiendo funciona en PCs que estan en un mismo dominio. Si revisas el link hay una parte adicional donde usa el `ConnectionOptions` alli defines las credenciales remotas co las cuales ejecutara la accion

Comment: Tienes razón @Leandro Tuttini, gracias por tu respuesta